# ¿Como filtrar datos de una hoja de excel con c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy realizando una tarea para poder leer un archivo de excel y poder filtrarlo por un dato en específico con EPPlus, lo cual lo hago de la siguiente manera con :

```
    public static void FilterDataXlsx(string xlsxFilePath)
    {
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        FileInfo fileInfoCFDIS_SIN_NOMINAS = new FileInfo(xlsxFilePath);

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfoCFDIS_SIN_NOMINAS))
        {
            string filterCriteria = "Hector";
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
            if (worksheet != null)
            {
                var filteredData = from cell in worksheet.Cells["A2:M20000"]
                                   where cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString() == filterCriteria
                                   select cell;

                // Crear un nuevo paquete Excel para almacenar los datos filtrados
                ExcelPackage filteredPackage = new ExcelPackage();
                ExcelWorksheet filteredWorksheet = filteredPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                // Copiar los datos filtrados al nuevo archivo
                int row = 1;
                foreach (var cell in filteredData)
                {
                    filteredWorksheet.Cells[row, cell.Start.Column].Value = cell.Value;
                    row++;
                }

                // Guardar el archivo filtrado en la ruta especificada
                FileInfo filteredFileInfo = new FileInfo(xlsxFilePath);
                filteredPackage.SaveAs(filteredFileInfo);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error al filtrar y guardar los datos");
            }

        }

    }
```

Asi es mi hoja antes de filtrarla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando la filtro solamente me trae

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente me trae el nombre pero no la demás información ni el encabezado, alguien me podría apoyar a ver por qué no sale la demás info, se los agradecería.

Comment: al parecer no estas agregando los parametros para filtrar la informacion.

Comment: Si estan en la parte de "filteredData" y ahi pongo el filtro